# How do you create Xamarin Forms class hierarchies inheriting from the 'Page' type?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

In Xamarin.Forms, I'm trying to create a page that I then subclass, like this:

```
public partial class PageA : ContentPage {
  public PageA() {InitializeComponent ();}
}

public partial class PageB : PageA {
  public PageB() : base() { ... }
}
```

Both of these pages are xaml pages with code behinds, but the PageB page is not working and I'm not sure why (I'm new to XAML, Xamarin, C# and basically coding in general).

I can't compile the code at the moment, since this line:

```
this.FindByName<Label>
```

gives me a warning of:

> PageB does not contain a definition for 'FindByName', and the best extension method ... requires a receiver of type 'Element'

And this line:

```
await Navigation.PushAsync(new PageB());
```

gives an error that PageB is not an Xamarin.Forms.Page. I don't know why PageA would be considered such a type, but it is.

Questions:

1. Is it possible to create subclasses of custom pages?
2. Why is a class that subclasses ContentPage (PageA) considered to be both of type 'Element' and of type 'Page'? And why is PageB NOT considered to be of those types?

I suspect I'm wildly off in many things here, so any corrections in how I've phrased the question and pointers to what question I SHOULD be asking are greatly welcome!

=========== EDIT

In response to a comment below:

***PageA***

The .cs file (codebehind) has the namespace `AppName.FolderName`, and the xaml has the x:Class attribute value `x:Class="AppName.FolderName.PageA"`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="AppName.FolderName.PageA">

             ... (some elements) ...

</ContentPage>
```

***PageB***

The .cs file (codebehind) has the namespace `AppName.FolderName.SubFolderName`, and the xaml has the x:Class attribute value `x:Class="AppName.FolderName.SubFolderName.PageB"`

And I have a reference with the following `using AppName.FolderName`, which gives me access to the `PageA` class

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="AppName.FolderName.SubFolderName.PageB">
</ContentPage>
```

Comment: Can you share the Xaml Code also please? and the namespaces of the code behind ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this

> FYI this code is from my app which is a working example

Create a base page as below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="Sthotraani.Views.BasePage">

</ContentPage>
```

your base page cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace Sthotraani.Views
{
    public partial class BasePage : ContentPage
    {
        public BasePage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

now derived page looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<views:BasePage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
                xmlns:views="clr-namespace:Sthotraani.Views;assembly=Sthotraani"
                x:Class="Sthotraani.Views.LoginPage"
                BackgroundColor="#009688"
                xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:Sthotraani.CustomControls;assembly=Sthotraani"
                xmlns:converters="clr-namespace:Sthotraani.Converters;assembly=Sthotraani"
                xmlns:behaviors="clr-namespace:Sthotraani.Behaviors;assembly=Sthotraani">

</views:BasePage>
```

derived page cs looks like this

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace Sthotraani.Views
{
    public partial class LoginPage : BasePage
    {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

This is a slight variation on [Krishna's excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44842288/199364).
(I would have made it a comment, but I wanted to show the code changes clearly.)

IF BasePage does not define any elements in XAML (see Krishna's answer - `<views:BasePage>` has no children), THEN `BasePage.xaml` **is not needed**; simply do this in `BasePage.xaml.cs`:

```
using Xamarin.Forms;

public abstract class BasePage : ContentPage
{
    public BasePage()
    {
        // Each sub-class calls InitializeComponent(); not needed here.
    }
}
```

Then your sub-page must call `InitializeComponent();`, as you normally do in a ContentPage constructor.

I think this is preferable design, as it would be surprising to NOT see `InitializeComponent();` in the derived page constructors; leaves reader wondering if it *should* be there but was accidentally left out. That is why I use this variation. **Each page declaration looks just like a normal content page, except that it inherits from BasePage instead of ContentPage.**
Trivial to change back and forth between a regular content page, and this subclass.
**I create one of these by using xamarin forms template for ContentPage, then changing base class to BasePage, in both C# and XAML.**

So, derived page C# becomes:

```
public partial class LoginPage : BasePage
{
    public LoginPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

and derived page XAML is as shown in Krishna's answer.