# Is it possible that my menu is Available for all my Screens - XamarinForms

Tags: xamarin, prisma

I have a menu with SideMenuView in xamarin , what I want to know if it is possible that when I slide my finger to the right the menu appears.
Now it only works for the main window for me, but the question is whether it can be set for all windows.

Xaml:

```xml
<Frame Padding="0" xct:SideMenuView.MainViewScaleFactor="1"
       xct:SideMenuView.MenuAppearanceType="SlideIn"
       xct:SideMenuView.MenuGestureEnabled="True" 
       xct:SideMenuView.MenuWidthPercentage="{OnPlatform Android=0.85, UWP=0.4, iOS=0.9}"
       xct:SideMenuView.Position="LeftMenu" 
       BackgroundColor="Transparent" CornerRadius="0"
       HasShadow="False" IsVisible="True">
```

c#:

```cs
switch (MenuState)
{
    case SideMenuState.MainViewShown:
        MenuState = SideMenuState.LeftMenuShown;
        break;
    case SideMenuState.LeftMenuShown:
        MenuState = SideMenuState.MainViewShown;
        break;
}
```

```
El ejemplo esta hecho con MVVM
```

Comment: Xaml:
<Frame
                        Padding="0"
            xct:SideMenuView.MainViewScaleFactor="1"
            xct:SideMenuView.MenuAppearanceType="SlideIn"
            xct:SideMenuView.MenuGestureEnabled="True"
            xct:SideMenuView.MenuWidthPercentage="{OnPlatform Android=0.85,UWP=0.4, iOS=0.9}"
            xct:SideMenuView.Position="LeftMenu"
            BackgroundColor="Transparent"
            CornerRadius="0"
            HasShadow="False"
            IsVisible="True">

Comment: code:
 switch (MenuState)
                {
                    case SideMenuState.MainViewShown:
                        MenuState = SideMenuState.LeftMenuShown;
                        break;
                    case SideMenuState.LeftMenuShown:
                        MenuState = SideMenuState.MainViewShown;
                        break;
                }

Comment: So far so good. You've shown MenuState getting set; how does that cause the menu to appear when finger slides? **Bottom line:** ALL code that involves `MenuState` will need to be on ALL the pages that should have the menu. If your page is a `ContentPage`, then define a `class BasePage : ContentPage` that includes all the xaml and code needed. Then make your pages inherit from `BasePage` instead of `ContentPage`.

Comment: See [Inherit from a custom BasePage](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44841689/199364).

Answer (score 0):

You could use control templates.

1. Create a ContentViewTemplate:

   ```
   <ContentView.Content>
    <xct:SideMenuView x:Name="sideMenuView">
         .....
    </xct:SideMenuView>
   </ContentView.Content>
   ```
2. Add this into Resources(App.xaml):

   ```
     <Application.Resources>
    <ControlTemplate x:Key="MainTemplate">
        <controls:MainTemplate></controls:MainTemplate>
    </ControlTemplate>
    </Application.Resources>
   ```
3. Use this template in content page:

   ```
    <ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:App1"
         x:Class="App1.MainPage"
          ControlTemplate="{StaticResource MainTemplate}">

       ....
    </ContentPage>
   ```

Comment: I forgot to add in the question that I am working with MVVM, would the process be the same?

Comment: How do you used with MVVM?

Comment: It is a design pattern that aims to separate the user interface part from the business logic part, thus making the visual part totally independent.